# Jackson ObjectMapper not reading JSON to POJO

Tags: json, gson, mapping, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have the following java object:

```
Record.class
    {
        long version;
        String data;
        String source;
    }
```

I am trying to use the **`data`** field and convert it to a Java class using object mapper.

```
data = "{
        \"myUuid\": \"af34b6ab-bebc-443b-af5c-53495905cb0b\",
        \"location\": \"UK\",
        \"clientName\": \"My_ClientName\",
        \"status\": \"SUCCESS\",
        \"activeDays\": 251
    }";
```

My corresponding Java class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ClientInfo implements TargetEntity {
    
    @JsonAlias("clientName")
    @JsonProperty("clientAccountId")
    String clientName;
    
    @JsonAlias("location")
    @JsonProperty("geo")
    String geo;
    
    @JsonAlias("status")
    @JsonProperty("clientStatus")
    String status;

    @JsonAlias("activeDays")
    @JsonProperty("numberOfDaysActive")
    int activeDays;

    @Override 
    public String getEntityName() {
        return "ClientInfo";
    }

    @Override public boolean isActiveForAtleast1Day() {
        return activeDays>0;
    }

}
```

Finally my code which I use:

```
  protected void buildClientInfo(Record clientRecord) {
        String data =  crmRecord.getData();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ClientInfo entityData = objectMapper.readValue(data, ClientInfo.class);

    }
```

My output is always and ObjectMapper is not able to read other values.

```
{
"activeDays" : 0
}
```

Using jackson-databind-2.9.x

What am I missing?
Weirdly - if I do `new Gson().fromJson(clientRecord.getData(), clazz)` I get the output I need except for the `isActiveForAtleast1Day`.

Comment: Could not reproduce this issue for the provided sources.  It is very likely that `data` field contains invalid JSON which fails quietly and thus only `int activeDays = 0` is initialized.

Comment: @AlexRudenko - thanks. I am thinking maybe my dependencies are to be blamed? Would you know what would be right dependencies to use if I use jackson-databind-2.9.x? I tried extracting the string as JSON and verfied that there is no issue there..  :(

Comment: I don't quite understand which dependencies you mean.  If you did not provide necessary dependencies for Jackson `jackson-annotations` & `jackson-core`, your code would not compile.

Comment: Okay.. understood thanks... I'll maybe debug more and see.  Not sure which direction to head.. ☹️

Answer (score 0):

Posting this code just for reference:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ClientInfo implements TargetEntity {
    
    @JsonAlias("clientName")
    @JsonProperty("clientAccountId")
    String clientName;
    
    @JsonAlias("location")
    @JsonProperty("geo")
    String geo;
    
    @JsonAlias("status")
    @JsonProperty("clientStatus")
    String status;

    @JsonAlias("activeDays")
    @JsonProperty("numberOfDaysActive")
    int activeDays;

    @Override
    public String getEntityName() {
        return "ClientInfo";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActiveForAtleast1Day() {
        return activeDays>0;
    }
// getters/setters
}
```

---

```
// assumption
public interface TargetEntity {

    String getEntityName();
    boolean isActiveForAtleast1Day();
}
```

Test code:

```
String data = "{\"myUuid\": \"af34b6ab-bebc-443b-af5c-53495905cb0b\",\"location\": \"UK\",\"clientName\": \"My_ClientName\",\"status\": \"SUCCESS\",\"activeDays\": 251}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClientInfo entityData = objectMapper.readValue(data, ClientInfo.class);
      
System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(entityData));
```

Output:

```
{
  "entityName" : "ClientInfo",
  "activeForAtleast1Day" : true,
  "clientAccountId" : "My_ClientName",
  "geo" : "UK",
  "clientStatus" : "SUCCESS",
  "numberOfDaysActive" : 251
}
```